# CountIfs operation in python

Tags: python

I am trying to replicate Excel countifs operation in my dataset using Python but I am not successful to get the correct output. Please help me to get the required output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' :[302896,302896,302896,302896,302896,302896,302896,302896,541646,541646,541646,541646,541646,541646,541646,541646,614663,658798,658798,658798,658798,658798,658798,658798,658798] ,
                   'Date' : [44659.7044791667,44659.7044791667,44659.7044791667,44659.7044791667,44659.7044791667,44659.7044791667,44659.7044791667,44659.7044791667,44663.973587963,44663.973587963,44663.973587963,44663.973587963,44663.973587963,44663.973587963,44663.973587963,44663.973587963,44744.3235185185,44687.8571643519,44687.8571643519,44702.4230324074,44702.4230324074,44702.4230324074,44702.4230324074,44702.4230324074,44702.4230324074],
                   'Risk' : ['Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Above Normal','Normal','High','High','High','High','High','High','High','High',
]})
```

My Try

```
Opp = lambda x:int(x== big_df1['ID'])
PrdDt= lambda x:datetime(x<= big_df1['Date'])
High = lambda x:int(x== 'High')
countRiskFactors = lambda row: Opp(row['ID']) + PrdDt(row['Date']) + int(row['Risk'] == 'High')

df['High'] = df.apply(countRiskFactors,axis=1)
```

Excel Formula -
High =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$26,$A2,$B$2:$B$26,"<="&$B2,$C$2:$C$26,"High")
Above Normal =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$26,$A2,$B$2:$B$26,"<="&$B2,$C$2:$C$26,"Above Normal")
Normal  =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$26,$A2,$B$2:$B$26,"<="&$B2,$C$2:$C$26,"Normal")

Expected output

[image]

Comment: Why is oppID 658798 `[2,2,8,8,8,8,8,8]` rather than `[2,2,6,6,6,6,6,6]`

Comment: @It_is_Chris i assume there are 2 rows below the bottom of the screenshot. Otherwise I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Yeah, that's why I was confused. If that is the case, I would just do `new_df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df).groupby(['ID', 'Date']).transform(sum)], axis=1)`

Comment: @It_is_Chris thank you for your reply yes output should be [2,2,8,8,8,8,8,8] rather than [2,2,6,6,6,6,6,6] because of the condition on 'Date' column <=(Less equal) not ==(equal) i think above code is group by ==('ID' and 'Date' ) but my requirement is where 'ID' whole column == @'ID' and 'Date' whole column <= @'Date' . Whop i am able to explain.

Comment: @It_is_Chris nicely done! I borrowed your `get_dummies` idea in my updated answer (but OP explained that there is an extra element of complexity)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
# convert Excel date to Python
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='D', origin='1899-12-30').dt.date

countifs = (pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['Risk'])], axis=1)
            .sort_values(by='Date')
            .groupby(['ID', 'Date']).sum()
            .groupby('ID').cumsum())

new_df = pd.merge(df, countifs, how='left', left_on=['ID', 'Date'], right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
      ID    Date        Risk Above Normal High Normal
0   302896  2022-04-08  Above Normal    8   0   0
1   302896  2022-04-08  Above Normal    8   0   0
2   302896  2022-04-08  Above Normal    8   0   0
3   302896  2022-04-08  Above Normal    8   0   0
4   302896  2022-04-08  Above Normal    8   0   0
5   302896  2022-04-08  Above Normal    8   0   0
6   302896  2022-04-08  Above Normal    8   0   0
7   302896  2022-04-08  Above Normal    8   0   0
8   541646  2022-04-12  Above Normal    8   0   0
9   541646  2022-04-12  Above Normal    8   0   0
10  541646  2022-04-12  Above Normal    8   0   0
11  541646  2022-04-12  Above Normal    8   0   0
12  541646  2022-04-12  Above Normal    8   0   0
13  541646  2022-04-12  Above Normal    8   0   0
14  541646  2022-04-12  Above Normal    8   0   0
15  541646  2022-04-12  Above Normal    8   0   0
16  614663  2022-07-02  Normal          0   0   1
17  658798  2022-05-06  High            0   2   0
18  658798  2022-05-06  High            0   2   0
19  658798  2022-05-21  High            0   8   0
20  658798  2022-05-21  High            0   8   0
21  658798  2022-05-21  High            0   8   0
22  658798  2022-05-21  High            0   8   0
23  658798  2022-05-21  High            0   8   0
24  658798  2022-05-21  High            0   8   0
```

Comment: thank you for your reply yes output should be [2,2,8,8,8,8,8,8] rather than [2,2,6,6,6,6,6,6] for column High because of the condition on 'Date' column <=(Less equal) not ==(equal) i think above code is group by ==('ID' and 'Date' ) but my requirement is where 'ID' whole column == @'ID' and 'Date' whole column <= @'Date' . Whop i am able to explain.

Comment: Thank you for updating the code, help is always appreciated. This partially solved my requirement when I am applying this to my complete dataset few places it is not matching the condition.

Comment: I added a sort, that might fix the issues. Otherwise could you show an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: please find the example dataset. I think it is because of the Date column (in MS excel it is looking only for date <= '3/21/2022  12:14:13 AM' and in this case, there is none hence the outcome is 0 but in your case, it is counting the rows it is coming as 8. ExampleDataset in the next comment

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' :[11371276,11371276,11371276,11371276,11371276,11371276,11371276,11371276,10625577,10625577,10625577,10625577,10625577,10625577,10625577,10625577],'Date' :['3/21/2022','3/21/2022','3/21/2022','3/21/2022','3/21/2022','3/21/2022','3/21/2022','3/21/2022','3/24/2022','3/24/2022','3/24/2022','3/24/2022','3/24/2022','3/24/2022','3/24/2022','3/24/2022'], 'Risk' :['N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N'],'Your':[8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8], 'Expt':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]})     
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] , format='%m/%d/%Y')